# Marketing Cloud Email Openers and Non Email openers

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I want to create a 2 new list from existing data extension of the people who has opened the email and not opened the emails of the journey email which I have sent recently.

Can you please help.

Thanks

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: Research and make an attempt at solving  your question .

Answer (score 0):

Under Email Studio > Tracking > Sends, you will see a seperate folder for Journey Builder email sends. You will have all the tracking details of the email there and you can export them into a cab and populate a list or data extension by manually importing csv.

If you want to automate the process, you will have to write a  query using  _Sent and _Open system view based on email send job id and join it with entry source using subscriber key.